# Efficient way to generate a coincidence matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis

I want to generate a simple coincidence matrix, I've looked for R packages but could not find one that does this calculation so far, I don't know if the English term for this matrix is different than the Portuguese one... so, that's what I need to do.

I have a matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  1    1    2     1
[2,]  1    2    3     1
[3,]  2    3    1     2
[4,]  1    2    3     3
```

A coincidence matrix will be calculated comparing each element row by row to generate a dissimilarity distance with the formula:

```
Diss = 1 - (Coincidences / (Coincidences + Discordance))
```

So my resulting matrix is an symmetrical one with dim 4x4 and diagonal elements equal 0, so in the example my A(1,2) would it be:

```
A(1,2) = 1 - (2 / 4) = 0.5
A(1,3) = 1 - (0/4) = 1.0
```

And so on...

I have created a function to generate this matrix:

```
cs_matrix <- function (x) {

  cs.mat <- matrix(rep(0,dim(x)[1]^2), ncol = dim(x)[1])

  for (i in 1:dim(x)[1]){

    for (j in 1:dim(x)[1]){

      cs.mat[i,j] <- 1 - (sum(x[i,] == x[j,]) / dim(x)[2])
    }
  } 
  return(cs.mat)
}
```

The function works fine, but my actual Data Set has 2560 observations of 4 variables, thus generating a 2560 x 2560 coincidence matrix, and it takes quite some time to do the calculation. I wonder if there is a more efficient way of calculating this or even if there is already a package that can calculate this dissimilarity distance. This matrix will be later used in Cluster Analysis.

Comment: Did you mean Diss = 1 - (Coincidences / (Coincidences + Discordance))?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the diagonal be zero, since each row is similar to itself?

Comment: Yes @Gabriel, thank you for point it out.

Comment: @JorisChau yes, the diagonal elements are equal to zero, I was with similarities values on my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `outer`

```
add <- function(x, y) sum(mat[x, ] == mat[y,])
nr <- seq_len(nrow(mat))
mat1 <- 1 - outer(nr, nr, Vectorize(add))/ncol(mat)
mat1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 0.00 0.50    1 0.75
#[2,] 0.50 0.00    1 0.25
#[3,] 1.00 1.00    0 1.00
#[4,] 0.75 0.25    1 0.00
```

If diagonal elements need to be 1 do `diag(mat1) <- 1`.

**data**

```
mat <- structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3), .Dim = c(4L,4L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at the outer function!